# best practice to handle Too many mysql connections

Tags: php, mysql, web-services, http

```
<?php
// Connect to mysql server
$link = mysql_connect(HOST, USER, PASSWORD);
if(!$link) {
    die('Could not connect to server: ' . mysql_error());
}

// Select database
$db = mysql_select_db(DATABASE);
if(!$db) {
    die('Cannot use the database');
}
mysql_set_charset('charset=utf8', $link); 

//code

?>
```

I am php beginer.I have written a simple php HTTP API which read some data from database and return in body. This API is accessed by many uses application **asynchronously**. When we increase the number of user more than 200 each second, i nam getting following warning

```
PHP Warning:  mysql_connect() [<a href='function.mysql-connect'>function.mysql-connect</a>]: Too many connections in /home/ws/public_html/include/get_details.php on line 3
```

I want to know best solution for it.

Thanks

Comment: are you on shared hosting? or?

Comment: purchase more bandwidth, server power ?

Comment: So I see `mysql_connect` and `mysql_select_db`. Do you also actually `mysql_close` the connection at the end??

Comment: You can organize a connection pool.

Comment: i am using dedicated server with Intel® Nehalem Quad-Core 2 x E5506 2.13GHz  16GB  2 × 1000GB  SW RAID 1 from http://iweb.com/smart-server-hosting/overview

Answer (score 1):

first you can use [mysqltuner](https://github.com/rackerhacker/MySQLTuner-perl) to check your db status. Other solution, use redis or memcache to reduce the connections. If you have your sessions stored in DB, try to change and use redis.[phpredis](https://github.com/nicolasff/phpredis)